# Как получить значение из таблицы на ajax?

Tags: ajax

Есть такая табличка:

```
  <tr>
    <td class="val">значение</td>
    <td><span class="del">удалить</span></td>
  </tr>
```

Ловлю клик по span

```
 $('table.class span.del').click(function(){
```

Как теперь получить по нему слово "значение" из этой же строки таблицы?

Достаточно ли здесь классов или надо внедрять id'шники что бы он понимал что мне именно соответствующее этому span значение нужно?

Answer (score 0):

Найти значение можно разными способами:

```js
$('table.class span.del').click(function(){
    //var tdVal =  $(this).closest('tr').find('.val').text();
    var tdVal =  $(this).parent().prev('.val').text();    
    console.log(tdVal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="class">
<tr>
    <td class="val">значение1</td>
    <td><span class="del">удалить1</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="val">значение2</td>
    <td><span class="del">удалить2</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="val">значение3</td>
    <td><span class="del">удалить3</span></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

А как значение передать в ajax - уже дело ваше

---

[parent](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0) - осуществляет поиск родительских элементов всех заданных элементов. Метод имеет один вариант использования:

[prev](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8) - для каждого из **выбранных элементов** находит предшествующий ему элемент (но только если он лежит на том же уровне иерархии DOM).

[closest](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA) - для каждого из **выбранных элементов**, `closest()` будет искать ближайший подходящий элемент из числа следующих: сам выбранный элемент, его родитель, его прародитель, и так далее, до начало дерева DOM.

[find](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85) - осуществляет поиск элементов внутри уже **выбранных элементов**.

Comment: В целом работает, только что-то у меня так консоль пустое значение выводит

Comment: @marrk2 значит структура не такая, как ты её написал в вопросе. обычно точный поиск происходит при точной и однотипной структуре.